# How to print out a list item based on its status?

Tags: java, list, for-loop, arraylist

I'm creating an eAuction system and I have a method for browsing auctions. Each auction has a status (OPEN or CLOSED) and I want the browseAuctions method to only print out auctions that are opened.

I've tried a number of if statements and it always keeps printing out every single auction.

The following code is a few things I've hardcoded to test the system

```
public List<Auction> auctionSystem() throws Exception {
    List<Auction> auctions = new LinkedList<Auction>();
    auctions.add(new Auction (35.50, 75.50, 40.00, users.get(3), LocalDateTime.now().minusSeconds(60), "Xbox", users.get(1), Status.OPEN));
    auctions.add(new Auction (27.00, 42.00, 32.00, users.get(2), LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(10), "PS3", users.get(1), Status.OPEN));
    auctions.add(new Auction (19.00, 21.00, 50.00, users.get(2), LocalDateTime.now().minusSeconds(1), "iPhone", users.get(1), Status.CLOSED));
    return auctions;
}
```

This is the Auction class constructor:

```
public Auction (double startPrice, double reservePrice, double currentBid, User highestBidder, LocalDateTime closeDate, String item, User seller, Status status) throws Exception {
    if (closeDate.isBefore(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(7))) {
        this.startPrice = startPrice;
        this.reservePrice = reservePrice;
        this.closeDate = closeDate;
        this.item = item;
        this.highestBidder = highestBidder;
        this.currentBid = currentBid;
        this.seller = seller;
        UP = currentBid * 0.20;
        LOW = currentBid * 0.10;
    } else {
        throw new Exception ("CloseDate error: " + closeDate.format(formatter));
    }
}
```

This is the `Status` class:

```
public enum Status {
    OPEN, CLOSED
}
```

This is the method inside the `Auction` class to browse auctions:

```
public void browseAuctions () {

    System.out.println("-----All Auctions-----");

    for (Auction a : auctions) {
        if (a.status.equals(Status.OPEN)){  
            System.out.println("Item: " + a.getItem());
            System.out.println("Current Bid: " + "£" + a.getCurrentBid());
            System.out.println("Close Date: " + a.getCloseDate());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `status` is ignored in the constructor, therefore all the `Auction` instances shall be *not* be qualified according to the condition in the loop. I wonder all pass and the only explanation is that the `Status.OPEN` is set by default, it means you have the following declaration in the code:

```
private Status status = Status.OPEN;
```

Since it is missing in the constructor, it is not set to a new passed value. These are problems with mutable fields, so I suggest you declare them `final` and resolve a default value with a secondary constructor:

```
private final Status status;
// the rest

public Auction (double sPrice, double rPrice, double currentBid, 
                User highestBidder, LocalDateTime closeDate, String item, User seller) 
{
    this(sPrice, rPrice, currentBid, highestBidder, closeDate, item, seller, Status.OPEN)
}
```

Anyway, to fix your issue, complete the constructor with:

```
this.status = status;
```